# Delete all the records from all the tables

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans

I am working on a project which is similar to my previous one, and I am trying to use previous app database. but the problem is previous database is full, Now I have a many tables to be deleted, I have one table in which I have all the names of table i.e. customer tables are created with their name and I have used another table in which there are names of customer with their tablename column. I want all the customer tables deleted and customer detail table empty..

Comment: which programming language you are using?

Comment: using Java, netbeans IDE

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy with mysql!

```
mysqldump -d -u someuser -p mydatabase customer_detail
```

`mysqldump` does a backup, or dump, of a database

`-d` specifies not to export the data, just the table structure

`-u someuser -p mydatabase` your DB credentials

`customer_detail` the name of the table you want in the dump-- this excludes all other tables not listed (if you want to keep other tables list them here as well).

You can dump to a file:

```
mysqldump -d -u someuser -p mydatabase customer_detail > mydatabase.sql
```

and then reimport:

```
mysql -u someuser -p anotherdatabase < mydatabase.sql
```